# Failed to get canonical path of `/tmp/kcm-grub2-0/boot/grub' (Grub2 Bootloader can't access Windows 8 because it is hibernated)

Tags: mount, windows, grub2, boot-loader

After playing with Grub Customizer and restart the computer, there is no Windows entry anymore. Booting to Linux its entry now disappears in both Grub Customizer and GRUB2 Bootloader. Normally, using the tool `Install/Recover Bootloader` in GRUB2 Bootloader and pointing it to the Windows partition (mountpoint: `/tmp/kcm-grub2-0`) should fix it, but now it fails because Windows is in hibernation (Windows 8's fast shut down mode is actually a kind of hibernation; I didn't know this until getting this trouble). After using this command

```
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda2 /tmp/kcm-grub2-0
```

and try again, there is another error:

```
Command: /usr/sbin/grub-install --root-directory /tmp/kcm-grub2-0 /dev/sda
Error code: 1
Error message:
Installing for i386-pc platform. /usr/sbin/grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/tmp/kcm-grub2-0/boot/grub'.
```

I have tried to google it but can't find any useful result. Do you have any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for most problem with booting.